# jQuery addClass of child to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/6EEjs/1/ that looks like:

```
<head><style>
    span.mw-uctop {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    li.mw-uctop {
        font-size: 8px;
        text-decoration: italic;
    }
</style><script>
    $("li").contents("span.mw-uctop").addClass("mw-uctop");
</script></head><body>
    <ul>
        <li class="">Text blurb 1 <span class="mw-uctop">(top)</span> ‎</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 2‎</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 3 <span class="mw-uctop">(top)</span> ‎</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 4</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 5</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 6</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 7 <span class="mw-uctop">(top)</span> ‎</li>
        <li class="">Text blurb 8 <span class="mw-uctop">(top)</span> ‎</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

What I am looking for as an end result is I want to add the class "mw-uctop" to all of the "li" elements that have a child with the "mw-uctop" class.  How do I do this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  You cannot have `<li>` elements on their own, they must be within a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element.

Comment: That is a chopped down version of the page for demonstration, they are inside <ul></ul>.

Comment: I added the <ul></ul> if it makes it easier to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.mw-uctop').closest('li').addClass('mw-uctop');
```

Comment: My solution also takes account with the .mw-uctop child not being direct child, but a descendant. It depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('li > .mw-uctop').parent().addClass('mw-uctop');
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "child" you mean "descendant," then:

```
 $("li:has(.mw-uctop)").addClass('mw-uctop');
```

If you really do mean child, try:

```
 $("li:has(> .mw-uctop)").addClass('mw-uctop');
```

Comment: `$("li:has(.mw-uctop)").addClass('mw-uctop');` works... `$("li:has(> .mw-uctop)").addClass('mw-uctop');` also works...

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
$('li').has('span.mw-uctop').addClass('mw-uctop');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/) :

```
$("li").has("span.mw-uctop").addClass("mw-uctop");
```

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.

Comment: this is the same as `$('li').has('span.mw-uctop').addClass('mw-uctop');` other than double quotes instead of single, and it also works...

Comment: @ShoeMaker - yes it is, several of the answers where posted at the same time, all of them seems to be correct, most of us already knew our answers would work, and now it's up to you figure out which one fits your needs the best, and accept one of the answers.

Comment: They all got up-voted, I'll pick whichever one I end up using shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more pure javascript oriented way to do it:

```
var query = document.querySelectorAll('li > .mw-uctop');
//there are other workarounds for query selector for older browsers (ie6/7)
for(i=0;i<=query.length;i++){
query[i].parentNode.className+= 'mw-uctop';
// For Testing: document.write(query[i].parentNode.className+"<br>");
}
```

Edit: oops one second
Edit: fixed

Comment: I up-voted yours too.  Although it came in later than the others and I already picked one, it works and is different enough. :)